# nested json array, one key has an array as its value

Tags: php, json, nested

I can build well formed JSON that looks like this:

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "parent_id": "0",
    "name": "Electronics",
    "children": [{
              "id": "2",
               "parent_id": "1",
               "name": "Television",
               "children": [{
              "id": "3",
               "parent_id": "2",
                "name": "Smart"
        }, {
               "id": "4",
               " parent_id": "2",
               "name": "4K Ultra"
        }, {
                 "id": "5",
                  "parent_id": "2",
            "                 name": "Curved"
        }]
    }]
}
```

But what I really want is JSON in this format:

```
[{
    "type": "view",
    "name": "db_view_1",
    "depends": [
        "db_table_15",
        "db_table_14",
        "db_table_1"
    ]
}, {
    "type": "view",
    "name": "db_view_2",
    "depends": [
        "db_table_4",
        "db_table_14"
    ]
}, {
    "type": "view",
    "name": "db_view_3",
    "depends": [
        "db_table_5",
        "db_table_14"
    ]
}]
```

As you can see in the 'depends' key, the value is an array of strings, with no key, just the value.

I used this PHP code to generate the first JSON output:

```
// Get the tree array from DB
$treeArray = getDataFromDatabase();

// Group by parent id
$treeArrayGroups = [];
foreach ($treeArray as $record) {
    $treeArrayGroups[$record['parent_id']][] = $record;
}

// Get the root
$rootArray = $treeArray[0];

// Transform the data
$outputTree = transformTree($treeArrayGroups, $rootArray);

// Output the response
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($outputTree);

/**
 * Transform the tree
 *
 * @param $treeArrayGroups
 * @param $rootArray
 * @return mixed
 */
function transformTree($treeArrayGroups, $rootArray)
{
    // Read through all nodes where parent is root array
    foreach ($treeArrayGroups[$rootArray['id']] as $child) {

    // If there is a group for that child, aka the child has children
        if (isset($treeArrayGroups[$child['id']])) {
            // Traverse into the child
            $newChild = transformTree($treeArrayGroups, $child);
        } else {
            $newChild = $child;
        }

        // Assign the child to the array of children in the root node
        $rootArray['children'][] = $newChild;
    }

    return $rootArray;
}

/**
 * Get all records from DB and return array
 *
 * @return array
 */

function getDataFromDatabase()
{


$config = parse_ini_file('config/myconfig.ini');
if($config == false){

echo "Can't find config file";

}


// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli('localhost',$config['username'], $config['password'], $config['dbname']);
//$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}



$nodes="SELECT id, parent_id, name FROM nested";


$records = $conn->query($nodes);
$output = mysqli_fetch_all($records, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

mysqli_close($conn);
return $output;

}
```

But, I don't know how to modify my code to produce the second JSON output.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The second JSON has nothing in common with the first, so I can't possibly see how to modify the code that produces the first JSON to produce the second JSON.

Comment: right, which node do you want as just an array of strings?

Comment: Hi, the 'depends' key.  And its not a necessity to modify the PHP code to get the output in the first JSON.  I just want a PHP loop to produce that JSON structure. Thanks!